# Not loading images on React using a JSON object as reference

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, image, src

this is my problem

I have this object Json below:

```
const imagesData = [
    {
        "imagepath": "./images/a.jpg",
        "title": "Red Car",
        "uploadeDate": "2 May 2020",
        "index": "0"
    }, {
        "imagepath": "./images/b.jpg",
        "title": "Blue Car",
        "uploadeDate": "2 May 2020",
        "index": "1"
    }, {
        "imagepath": "./images/c.jpg",
        "title": "Green Car",
        "uploadeDate": "2 May 2020",
        "index": "2"
    }

]
```

So my code is using the property of this object called "imagepath" to use it on the src of the tag img

```
const card = imagesData.map(function (obj, ind) {
       
        return (
            <div className='card'>
                <img src={obj.imagepath} />
                <span>{obj.title}</span>
            </div>
        )
```

so the problem is that the images are not loading, i have already checked the path and it is right

this is a picture of how it shows on my screen:

[image]

One observation is that if i try to import the images by
 `import car1 from './images/a.jpg`

and after this i put the variable car1 like below
`<img src={car1} />`

it works fine !. But i need a solution that i reference that path of the image from a json object !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should keep your images folder in the **public Folder** and then you can try this directly without importing.

```
const imagesData = [
    {
        "imagepath": '/images/a.jpg',
        "title": "Red Car",
        "uploadeDate": "2 May 2020",
        "index": "0"
    }, {
        "imagepath": '/images/b.jpg',
        "title": "Blue Car",
        "uploadeDate": "2 May 2020",
        "index": "1"
    }, {
        "imagepath": '/images/c.jpg',
        "title": "Green Car",
        "uploadeDate": "2 May 2020",
        "index": "2"
    }

]
```

Comment: Thank you !, that worked !!! Can you explain me the utility of the folder public ?? I`m new in React so i`m still learning