# How do i have an assets file that i can use in any file in my react app without always having to navigate to the assets folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, assets, alassetslibrary

How to use `import "assets/css/"` in any directory within my app
instead of this `import "../assets/css/"`

Answer (score 1):

It called **Absolute Path Imports**

If you using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), create file called `.env` with following content at the root of your project and restart the dev server and you are good to go:

```
NODE_PATH=src/
```

Otherwise add following to `webpack.config.js` ([Module Resolution](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/)):

```
resolve: { modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, './src'), 'node_modules'] };
```

Comment: Setting NODE_PATH to resolve modules absolutely has been deprecated in favor of setting baseUrl in jsconfig.json (or tsconfig.json if you are using TypeScript) and will be removed in a future major release of create-react-app.

Comment: And somehow with i can't require some dependency like,  AppBar from 'material-ui/core/AppBar' isn't working anymore

Comment: So use `jsconfig.json` instead then. the concept is the same, you just need to config NODE_PATH somewhere

Answer (score 0):

## I think you can use postinstall

It allows you to create aliases for different folders in your app. check it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postinstall)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep your file in the public Folder and then you can try this directly without importing.

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63961058/8425297